# Is it possible to control request data?

Tags: iis, filter, request

I want to control request content(GET,POST) on IIS side. Is that possible? By control I mean filter characters or strings. Also is it possible to to check if request has only certain list of variables(e.g `foo` and `bar` for request `http://site?foo=a&bar=b`).

Comment: Are you using an ASP.NET application? Why not just check the query string?

Comment: Yes, I'm using. ASP.net application. But using the approach you offered I have to check each string on each request. That means that in each .aspx file i have to write code that checks request string.

Comment: Can you add more details to the question? What exactly do you want to do with the query string? I am assuming whatever it is you are trying to do can be handled with URL rewrite rules.

Comment: I want to filter(check if string contains special characters and strings like `' or ''='` and other) request string. But I want to do it in one place. Therefore i was wondering if IIS provides it.

Comment: No, you don't. You can use an HttpModule.

Comment: could you provide me simple example or just a link?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.aspx